# What does `s.?('').?.?` mean?

Tags: ruby

I'm following the ruby on rails guide written by Micheal Harl. I"m wondering what `?('').?.?` means in the code below.

```
def string_shuffle(s)
  s.?('').?.?
end
string_shuffle("foobar")
# => "oobfra"
```

Comment: This is a `fill in ?` question and you should make it clearer. Your title is really misleading now. People might think that Ruby/Rails has that kinda syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be replaced with methods, like bellow:

```
def string_shuffle(s)
  s.split('').shuffle.join
end
```

---

```
def string_shuffle(s)
  s.split('').shuffle.join
end
string_shuffle("foobar")
# => "oafrob"
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much! I just realized that it is an exercise and we should replace the `?` with methods...Thanks! Very helpful!

Comment: and you did your home work complete :)))

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything. It's a syntax error. That code is not legal Ruby.